# Control key auto pressed when using vim over SSH through cygwin

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin

I'm using cygwin and sometimes, when I am typing in vim on a file over ssh and I switch to a different window and minimize cygwin and then come back to cygwin sometime later, I get a problem.

The problem is that for some reason, my keyboard doesn't work normally anymore, and it appears that for some reason, it thinks that my Control key on my keyboard is always being pressed. I know this because when I press just the 'V' key on my keyboard, vim says it's in Visual Block mode, and when I just press the 'R' key, it tries to Redo any changes.

The bad thing is that this also means that I can't actually exit from vim because I can press the : key, but then pressing wq doesn't actually enter in the normal wq symbols because it's interpreting it as ctrl w, ctrl q.

The only way I can fix it is by closing the entire window and restarting cygwin, but this means I lose any unsaved work, which is annoying.

Note: This doesn't happen when I use vim locally in cygwin (not over SSH)

What is causing this problem?

Comment: As a temporary solution perhaps you could use a multiplexer such as tmux or screens. If the bug occurs, you can just restart cygwin and then reattach to the previous session and at least you won't lose your work.

Comment: Does this *only* happen in Vim? Or also outside of Vim (i.e. in the shell, or some other application)?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker this only seems to happen in Vim, although sometimes, pressing the up key at the bash prompt stops working as well

Comment: @Carpetsmoker actually, it's not just vim, I was just in my bash prompt and all my keys just stopped working like normal and even the arrow keys wrote characters to the prompt instead of behaving like arrow keys